# Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

Tags: magento2, database, magento-2.0

```
    CREATE TABLE `admin_user` (
      `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'User ID',
      `firstname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User First Name',
      `lastname` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Last Name',
      `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Email',
      `username` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Login',
      `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'User Password',
      `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'User Created Time',


is here is the problem--->`modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'User Modified Time',

      `logdate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'User Last Login Time',
      `lognum` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'User Login Number',
      `reload_acl_flag` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Reload ACL',
      `is_active` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'User Is Active',
      `extra` text COMMENT 'User Extra Data',
      `rp_token` text COMMENT 'Reset Password Link[...]
```

MySQL said: Documentation
    #1293 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

I am installing a new **magneto2** theme while importing sql I got this error.

I am using sql version PHP Version **5.6.30** on a PLESK server

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
`modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'User Modified Time'
```

to

```
`modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 COMMENT 'User Modified Time'
```

And while updating record, save **modified** value to current time programatically.

Comment: SO it's a mistake in theme SQL  ?  or some Magento requirements  that I am not following

Comment: No mistake. As per your MySQL version, only one column of type TIMESTAMP can have CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value.

Comment: i had same issue then I found that I was running myql 5.5 so it was causing this issue. Because from mysql 5.6 it is allowing multiple timestamp update statements